# Local tables are created in Access by SSMA

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I used SQL Server Migration Assistant to migrate my tables from Access to SQL Server. I now have my tables linked. However, I can see that the Migration assistant created a few tables in Access which are name something like:

```
SSMS$TABLE1$LOCAL 
SSMA$TABLE2$LOCAL etc
```

I am guessing that SSMA renamed my local tables before linking the SQL server tables to prevent naming conflict but I am not sure.

Why are these tables created? Should I delete them?

Comment: Were there any errors or crushes while migration? Maybe SSMA had exited before clean up? I have not seen such behavior.